# Text input inserting wrong value into list item

Tags: javascript

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/H5bRH/

Every time I click on the submit button, it should insert what I typed into a new li item.

But instead of that, it inserts what I typed the first time PLUS the new value that I typed. Play with my jsfiddle to see what I mean.

How do I fix this so that it only adds what the user inputs into the form?

I assume there's something wrong here:

```
function saveTweet() {
    var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet");
    var tweetName = tweet.value;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = tweetName;
    var ul = document.getElementById("tweets");
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: You're sliding the LI element added on the previous click down, not the one added now

Answer (score 2):

You have attached 2 **`click`** event to **`save`** button.

1. `button.onclick = saveTweet;`
2. Using jQuery `$("#saveTweet").click(function ()`

---

```
$("#saveTweet").click(function () {
    var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet");
    var tweetName = tweet.value;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = tweetName;
    var ul = document.getElementById("tweets");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    $("li").slideDown("fast");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5bRH/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just reduce all that code to :

```
$("#saveTweet").click(function () {
    $('#tweets').append('<li>' + $("#tweet").val() + '</li>')
    $("li").slideDown("fast");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/H5bRH/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having two click handlers for the #saveTweet button, move the slideDown call to your saveTweet function.

```
function saveTweet() {
    var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet");
    var tweetName = tweet.value;
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = tweetName;
    var ul = document.getElementById("tweets");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    $("li").slideDown("fast");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you bind two click handlers on the `#saveTweet` element.

One to add the content, and one to animate the `li` elements..

In your case the animated one is occuring first and the appending second.. so you always animate the previously added element...

Since you use jQuery anyway, why not use that for all your interactions ?

```
$(function () {
    var button = $("#saveTweet");

    button.on('click', function () {
        var tweet = $("#tweet"),
            ul = $("#tweets"),
            tweetName = tweet.val(),
            li = $('<li>', {html: tweetName});

        ul.append(li);
        li.slideDown("fast");
    });
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Y9cY3/1/